# At most two elements give 1 to n

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $m$. Let $n$ ( $= n(m)$) be the largest positive integer for which there exists some subset $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\} \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of $m$ positive integers between $1$ and $n$ such that for every integer $1 \leq b \leq n$, there are $1 \leq i \leq j \leq m$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \{-1,0,1\}$ with $b=\lambda_1 a_i + \lambda_2 a_j$.
I have got $\frac{m^2}{2}+O(m)\le n\le\frac{m^2}{1+\frac{2}{3\pi}}+O(m)$. Can we improve the bounds?

Comment: Please ask a question (with a question mark at the end).

Comment: The simpler case is the *postage stamp problem*.

Comment: The way you are asking strongly makes me to suspect that this is a question from a homework / midterm exam / whatever else in this spirit. Could you clarify the source of the problem?

Comment: @Seva In an exam it was a trivial problem. I'm now doing further research.

Comment: I edited with a clearer presentation of what I interpreted the meaning of the question to be. Apologies if I got something wrong.

Comment: From brute force enumeration, for $m=1,\ldots,8$ the maximal $n$ are $2,6,10,16,24,32,40,52$, which does not appear in OEIS. But this does not answer the question of a general upper bound (if that is what the question is asking).

Comment: @SamHopkins, ah, I see.  I edited with the assumption that the idiosyncrasies in presentation were those of the OP.  Since they were not, I have rolled back to your version.

Comment: For what it is worth, this seems to be essentially equivalent to the following question: Given an integer $n>0$, what is the smallest size of a subset $B\subseteq[-n,n]$ with $0\in B=-B$ such that $[-n,n]\subseteq 2B$?